# how to Conditionally add values to a matrix without using a for loop?

Tags: matlab

I have written a for loop code and I want to write in more succinct way without using a `for` loop, but instead use matrix conditional.
I am teaching myself matlab and I would appreciate any feedback.

I want to create a new matrix, the first column is `y`, and the second column is filled with zero except for the `y`'s whose indices are contained in the indices matrix. And in the latter case, add 1 instead of 0.

Thanks.

```
y=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7];
indices=[1;3;5];
[m,n]=size(y);
tem=zeros(m,1);

data=[y,tem];

[r,c]=size(indices);
for i=1:r
  a=indices(i);
  data(a,2 )=1;
end

Output: 
data =

 1     1
 2     0
 3     1
 4     0
 5     1
 6     0
 7     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter alternative:

```
data = [y(:), full(sparse(indices, 1, 1, numel(y), 1))];
```

The resulting matrix `data` is composed of two column vectors: `y(:)` and a `sparse` array, with "1"s at the positions corresponding to `indices`.

Using proper initialization and sparse matrices can be really useful in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
data = zeros( m, 2 );
data(:,1) = y;
data( indices, 2 ) = 1;
```